# ngrx select is not working while action dispatch successfully

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an Angular application where I am trying to fetch some data from the store using NgRx. I have defined an action to load the data, an effect to fetch the data from an API, a reducer to update the store with the data, and a selector to fetch the data from the store. However, I am having trouble fetching the data using the selector.

Here is my code:

```
//action.ts
    
    
export const loadPins = createAction('[map component] load pins');
export const loadPinsSuccess = createAction('[map component] load pins success', props<{apartmentLocations: IApartmentGeoLocations}>());
    
// effect.ts


fetchApartmentLocations$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(loadPins),
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.mapService
        .fetchMapPins()
        .pipe(map((apartmentLocations) => loadPinsSuccess({ apartmentLocations })))
    )
  )
);

// reducer.ts

const initialState: IAppState = {
  apartmentLocations: {},
};

export const createMapReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(loadPinsSuccess, (state, { apartmentLocations }) => {
    console.log('on ~ state:', state);
    return {
      ...state,
      apartmentLocations: apartmentLocations
    };
  })
);




// selector.ts


export const apartmentLocationsSelector = createFeatureSelector<IAppState>('apartmentLocations');
export const selectApartmentLocations = createSelector(
  apartmentLocationsSelector,
  (state: IAppState) => state.apartmentLocations
);
```

In my MapContainerComponent, I dispatch the loadPins() action on initialization and then try to fetch the data using the selector in the ngOnInit() function.

```
constructor(private store: Store<{ apartmentLocations: {} }>) {
  (mapboxgl as any).accessToken = environment.mapBox.accessToken;

  this.store.dispatch(loadPins());
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.pipe(select(selectApartmentLocations)).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('this.store.pipe ~ data:', data);
    /* Need to debug further why selector is */
  });
}
```

with redux dev tool, i can clearly see that, store is filled with data.

[image]
However, I am not getting any data in the console when the loadPinsSuccessful event occurs. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I thought the selector would subscribe whenever the store value has changed.

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you inspect your state and is it filled with the expected data?

Comment: yes it is filled with the data

Comment: Try subscribing to the selector before dispatching the action, although I would expect the way you have it should still pick up the last value.

Comment: Tried but bot working. Getting error like: apartmentLocations is undefined @wlf

Comment: Try using optional chaining in your selector like: `state?.apartmentLocations`. If that doesnt worth create a minimal reproducible example on stackblitz or similar.